# How two transfer one dimension data to two two dimension

Tags: apache-spark

I have data like this:

```
 2014 a 1
 2015 b 2
 2014 a 2
 2015 c 4
 2014 b 2
```

How to transfer it to:

```
       a  b  c
 2014  3  2  0
 2015  0  2  4
```

in Spark.
thanks.

Comment: @Ares I filter by the type and fullOuterJoin them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a protopyical application of a pivot table

```
df.show()
//
//+------+------+----+
//|letter|number|year|
//+------+------+----+
//|     a|     1|2014|
//|     b|     2|2015|
//|     a|     2|2014|
//|     c|     4|2015|
//|     b|     2|2014|
//+------+------+----+
val pivot  = df.groupBy("year")
 .pivot("letter")
 .sum("number")
 .na.fill(0,Seq("a")) 
 .na.fill(0,Seq("c"))

 pivot.show()
//+----+---+---+---+
//|year|  a|  b|  c|
//+----+---+---+---+
//|2014|  3|  2|  0|
//|2015|  0|  2|  4|
//+----+---+---+---+
```